# How to apply an alphanumeric sort in XSLT

Tags: xslt, sorting, alphanumeric

Based on the following XML, what is the best way to achieve an alphanumeric sort in XSL?

***Edit***: to clarify, the XML below is just a simple sample the real XML would contain much more variant values.

```
<colors>
  <item>
    <label>Yellow 100</label>
  </item>
  <item>
    <label>Blue 12</label>
  </item>
  <item>
    <label>Orange 3</label>
  </item>
  <item>
    <label>Yellow 10</label>
  </item>
  <item>
    <label>Orange 26</label>
  </item>
  <item>
    <label>Blue 117</label>
  </item>
</colors>
```

E.g. I want a final outcome in this order:

```
Blue 12, Blue 117, Orange 3, Orange 26, Yellow 10, Yellow 100
```

This is "*effectively*" what I would want.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="colors/item">
  <xsl:sort select="label" data-type="text" order="ascending"/><!--1st sort-->
  <xsl:sort select="label" data-type="number" order="ascending"/><!--2nd sort-->
</xsl:apply-templates>   

<xsl:template match="item">
  <xsl:value-of select="label"/>
  <xsl:if test="position() != last()">,</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: I updated my answer with a more generic approach to the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Splitting the label text into text and number part using `substring-before` and `substring-after` will do in your example (however, this is not a general approach, but you get the idea):

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="colors/item">
      <xsl:sort select="substring-before(label, ' ')" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      <!--1st sort-->
      <xsl:sort select="substring-after(label, ' ')" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
      <!--2nd sort-->
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:value-of select="label"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

This gives the following output:

```
Blue 12, Blue 117, Orange 3, Orange 26, Yellow 10, Yellow 100
```

---

**Update**

A more generic way to solve your sorting problem would be to have the `select` attribute of the `xls:sort` element contain a string which is sortable according to the sort rules that you expect. E.g. in this string all numbers could be padded with leading 0's so that lexicgraphically sorting them as `data-type="text"` will result in the correct alphanumeric order.

If you are using the XSLT engine of .NET you could use a simple extension function in C# to pad numbers with leading 0's:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:myExt="urn:myExtension"
                xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
                exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl myExt">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <msxsl:script language="C#" implements-prefix="myExt">

    <![CDATA[
        private static string PadMatch(Match match)
        {
            // pad numbers with zeros to a maximum length of the largest int value 
            int maxLength = int.MaxValue.ToString().Length;
            return match.Value.PadLeft(maxLength, '0');
        }

        public string padNumbers(string text)
        {
            return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(text, "[0-9]+", new System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchEvaluator(PadMatch));
        }
    ]]>

  </msxsl:script>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <sorted>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="colors/item">
        <xsl:sort select="myExt:padNumbers(label)" data-type="text" order="ascending"/>
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </sorted>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="item">
    <xsl:value-of select="label"/>
    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks divo... yeah I guess my sample data is a bit too generic ;-)  In reality there may not be any delimiter and/or the position of the digits could be anywhere.